# Iterating Hashmap in jsp and Showing Data in Dynamically Generated Table

Tags: hashmap, tr

I am having hashmap in jsp.

I want to print all the values that hashmap contains in a table. The table should generated dynamically and after 3 columns next values should be displayed in next row and so on..Using jstl or any tag library.

So if hashmap contains 6 values then  HTML generated should be:

```
<table>
     <tr>
        <td> val1 </td> 
        <td> val2 </td>
        <td> val3 </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td> val1 </td> 
        <td> val2 </td>
        <td> val3 </td>
     </tr>

</table>
```

If hashmap contains 8 values then  HTML generated should be:

```
<table>
     <tr>
        <td> val1 </td> 
        <td> val2 </td>
        <td> val3 </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td> val4 </td> 
        <td> val5 </td>
        <td> val6 </td>
     </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> val7 </td> 
        <td> val8 </td>
     </tr>

</table>
```

So as per number of values the  number of rows should get added to table. How do I do that in jsp... either using jstl tags or any custom tag library?

Answer (score 0):

Simply add the following java code in your jsp

```
  <table>
    <%
     int count=0;
      Iterator itr = yourMap.iterator();
      while(itr.hasNext()) {
      String key = itr.next();
      if(count  ==0) {
  %> 
     <tr> 
<% }  %>
   <td><% =yourMap.get(key) %></td>
      <%
          count ++;
   if(count ==3 ) {
      count =0;
   %>
     </tr>
    <%>
}
</table>
```

Here I am assuing your map is `<String,String>` and please import relevant classes for map and iterator. Any JSP tutorial can tell you how o do that